# Stack overflow exception on itextsharp document.close

Tags: c#, pdf, exception, itext

I am merging multiple PDF into one single file. 
here is my code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FolderName);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(PdfOutputFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();
            foreach (string percorsoFile in files)
            {
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(percorsoFile);
                int numpagine = reader.NumberOfPages - PageAddedByWord;
                for (int pagina = 1; pagina <= numpagine; pagina++)
                {
                    int rotazione = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagina).Rotation;
                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pagina);
                    doc.NewPage();
                    if (rotazione == 90 || rotazione == 270)
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagina).Height);
                    else
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0f, 0f);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
```

And I get stack overflow exception on the `doc.Close()` line, but I can't understand why. I close every reader as soon as I am done with that file. I get this exception only with large sets of pdf (like 2000).
thank's for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED, I used PdfSmartCopy instead of pdfwriter. Now the code looks like this

```
 Document doc = new Document();
            PdfSmartCopy pdfCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms);
            doc.Open();
            foreach (var percorsoFilePdf in files)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(percorsoFilePdf);
                int numpagine = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int I = 1; I <= numpagine-PageAddedByWord; I++)
                {
                    doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                    PdfImportedPage page = pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, I);
                    pdfCopy.AddPage(page);
                }
                //Clean up
                //pdfCopy.FreeReader(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            //Clean up
            doc.Close();
            SharedMethods.MemoryStreamToFile(ms, PdfOutputFile);
```

also using a memorystream instead of a file stream is much faster, and the process doesn't get "too large".

Comment: Great answer! I don't know if you can accept your own answer. If so, you should do it!